# Get Current Location on Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT

Tags: android, locationlistener, android-geofence

> I have to update `geoFence` on exit. For that I need current location at that point.

**When my app is closed** I don't have listener for `onLocationChanged`. And in order to 
update geoFence I require my location. Is their any way to get current Location at `Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT`

```
public void broadcastUpdateGeoFences() {
        MainActivity.isGeoFenceAdded = false;//It tells to update geoFence
        Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.RECEIVER_GEOFENCE);
        intent.putExtra("done", 1);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

**Broadcast Receiver in MainActivity**

```
   private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                int resultCode = bundle.getInt("done");
                if (resultCode == 1) {

                    if(!MainActivity.isGeoFenceAdded){
                        updateGeoFencesOnCurrentExit();//I need current location here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Every thing working fine. But **Unable to find a way to pass currentLocation** at exit when app is closed.

```
private void updateGeoFencesOnCurrentExit(Location currentLocation){
            locationHandler.updateGeoFences(currentLocation);
}
```

Comment: Are you using an Intent Service for this?

Comment: Yes I am and I know it should be a Broadcast receiver

Comment: Where is your actual Add Geofences request?

Answer (score 0):

You can Implement LocationListener interface in your broadcast and use override method onLocationChanged like this

```
    @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    location.getLongitude();
    location.getLatitude();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using a LocationListener inside an IntentService or BroadcastReceiver, since they can be destroyed once the function (onHandleIntent or onReceive) has exited. I would use a PendingIntent with LocationManager to request a single update once you get the geofence event. I have example apps to demonstrate how to request location updates using a PendingIntent on github (https://github.com/pablobaxter/AndroidLocationExamples).

Edit:

FYI, IntentService is not wrong. You are just running the `onHandleIntent` logic in a background thread vs `onReceive` running on the main thread.

Comment: IntentService is bad because on Android Oreo you'll get exception when try to launch IntentService from background